# In-memory compression of a Zip file

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I want to compress files into Zip in-memory (I will store the result on a database instead of creating files in the file system).

How can I read the raw content for the compressed Zip file ?. I can't see any property to read that content, or any method to save that content into an Stream or any other in-memory structure.

```
function GetZip(UncompressedFile: TStream): TBytes; 
var AZipFile: TZipFile;
begin
  AZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    AZipFile.Add(UncompressedFile);
    Result := AZipFile.Data;  // ?? How to get the compressed file without saving it to the file system ??
  finally
    AZipfile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thank you.

Comment: As per [`TZipFile.Open()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Open) you can also use `TStream` for both reading and writing.

Comment: That's interesting @AmigoJack. So, if I Open the Zip object with an empty Stream, then after adding files I can read that Stream to get the compressed file raw data ?. Thank you, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Simply use a `TMemoryStream` as the `TStream` to write to. Or better, in your case, you even use a `TBlobStream` or whatever your DataSet's `CreateBlobStream()` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to AmigoJack and Remy Lebeau for letting me know that I can use the Zip input Stream to also get the result.

This works fine :

```
function Zip_AddFile(FileToAdd: TStream; Title: string): TBytes; overload; 
begin
   Result := Zip_AddFile([], FileToAdd, Title);
end;

function Zip_AddFile(Zip: TBytes; FileToAdd: TStream; Title: string): TBytes; overload;
var AZipFile: TZipFile;
    ZipStream: TBytesStream;
begin
  ZipStream := TBytesStream.Create(Zip);
  AZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    AZipFile.Open(ZipStream, zmReadWrite);
    AZipFile.Add(FileToAdd, Title);
    AZipFile.Close;
    Result := ZipStream.Bytes;
  finally
    AZipfile.Free;
    ZipStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: why `zmReadWrite`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I call this routine a few times to add several files into the same Zip file (that's why I have an overloaded version that can accept a Zip file parameter). It needs zmReadWrite to add the new file to the existing Zip, if I use zmWrite the resulting Zip only contains the last file added.